# Installing certificates on Kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes

I just started to explore Kubernetes and I deployed a service in a container on Kubernetes which is running on a cloud.

My service requires to make a call to a database which requires a certificate for authentication. I am wondering what would be the best practice to store/install the certificate on Kubernetes

I need to access the certificate from my code which I am using as follows

```
const (
    serverCertificate = "./cert/api.cer"
    serverPrivateKey  = "./cert/api.key"
)
creds, err := credentials.NewServerTLSFromFile(serverCertificate, serverPrivateKey)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could store the certificate in a Kubernetes Secret: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Here is an example on how to do so:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#creating-a-secret-using-kubectl-create-secret

Comment: Sure. Any idea on how I can access the certificate from my code. I edited the question with my code

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod describes how to project a secret as file into your container.  Put your certificate as a secret then project it into your container wherever you want.

Comment: @Dancemachine This might work but I am trying too keep my code unchanged for now instead I want to access the certificates from ./cert folder on kubernetes

Comment: Certificates can be kept in K8S Secrets and can be mounted on any folder in any folder in the container. In your case ./cert. `To use a secret, a pod needs to reference the secret. A secret can be used with a pod in two ways: as files in a volume mounted on one or more of its containers, or used by kubelet when pulling images for the pod.` https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#overview-of-secrets